# Event listening with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-plugins

I'm using a jQuery plugin called "[backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch)". Within the description it says that `backstretch.show` is called every time an image is changed. How would I go about listening for this event and getting it to perform another function when its called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
$(".foo").backstretch("...");
```

Then:

```
$(".foo").on("backstretch.show", function () {
    /* My code here */
});
```

If you're using the static version:

```
$.backstretch("...")
```

You may have to bind the event handler to the body:

```
$(document.body).on("backstretch.show", function () { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

An event needs two things to know what to listen for, the event type (in this case, `"backstretch.show"`, and the target. It looks like you apply `.backstretch()` to a jQuery set, so you probably want to register your handler on elements of that set for the target, [which are what get the event](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/blob/master/src/jquery.backstretch.js#L215-217).

So I'd recommend something like:

```
$("something").backstretch(/* ... */).on("backstretch.show", function () { 
     //do something
});
```